# Change color in text from cell with VBA excel

Tags: excel, vba

I want to change some text when saving to worksheet, the cell has multiple textbox values together.

When textbox is colored red in `VBA-excel`, it has to save that text value in the cell in red font.
When it is not red, it has to save in black font color.

```
Range("w" & lmaxrows + 1).Value = "S " & TextBox42.Value & " |VP " & TextBox43.Value & " |NP " & TextBox47.Value & " |E " & TextBox48.Value

If TextBox42.BackColor = vbRed Then
    With Range("w" & lmaxrows)
    d = "S " & TextBox42.Value
    If Range("w" & lmaxrows).Value > "" Then Replace(Range("w"), d, Range("w")).Font.Color = vbRed Range("w")).Font.Color = vbRed
end if 
end if
```

I have this for now, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

How about checking the length of your textbox and then using that to change the color of that many characters on the Cell:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Value = TextBox1.Text & " some other text"
    lengthofRed = Len(TextBox1.Text)
    'check the length of the text box
    If TextBox1.BackColor = vbRed Then
        Sheet1.Cells(1, 1).Characters(1, lengthofRed).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT:**

Changing the above to match your code, I believe the following should do what you expect:

```
Range("w" & lmaxrows + 1).Value = "S " & TextBox42.Value & " |VP " & TextBox43.Value & " |NP " & TextBox47.Value & " |E " & TextBox48.Value

If TextBox42.BackColor = vbRed Then
    With Range("w" & lmaxrows)
    d = "S " & TextBox42.Value
    If Range("w" & lmaxrows).Value > "" Then
        Range("W" & lmaxrows + 1).Characters(1, Len(d)).Font.Color = vbRed
    End If
End If
```